Realm / React Native problem after update
After upgrading packages and gradlew version 8.4.1 / Java 17 and after a 1000 issues and fixes I'm down to one problem:

What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':realm:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':realm:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.facebook.react:react-android:.
     Required by:
         project :realm

Packages:
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.73.9",
...
"realm": "^12.2.1"

build.gradle has
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-android:+"

and
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

Which fixed a bunch of other package issues. Any ideas?
